# Synchronising with mutex and relaxed memory order atomic

Tags: c++, c++17, atomic, memory-barriers, stdatomic

I have a shared data structure that is already internally synchronised with a mutex. Can I use an atomic with memory order relaxed to signal changes. A very simplified view of what I mean in code

Thread 1

```cpp
shared_conf.set("somekey","someval");
is_reconfigured.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
```

Thread 2

```
if (is_reconfigured.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
  inspect_shared_conf();
}
```

Is it guaranteed that I'll see updates in the shared_map?; the shared map itself internally synchronises every write/read call with a mutex

Comment: By "internally synchronized" do you mean that there is a mutex that `shared_conf::set()` and `inspect_shared_conf()` both lock when they start and unlock when they complete?

Comment: At the very least, with the code as it stands, `inspect_shared_conf` could start running while `shared_conf::set()` still holds the mutex, and so Thread 2 would have to sleep until `shared_conf::set()` completes and unlocks the mutex.  Would that be a problem for you?  That particular issue wouldn't affect correctness, but could be a performance hit.

Comment: If the spurious mutex contention isn't a problem, then I think I can prove that the code is otherwise correct: `inspect_shared_conf()`, by the time it successfully takes the lock, will see the updates made by `shared_conf::set()`.

Comment: Yes I meant that set will take a lock and release when done; similarly load will do the same, thanks for the clear answer, now I know what to do :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example code will work, and yes, you will see the updates.  The relaxed ordering will give you the correct behavior.  That said, it may not actually be optimal in terms of performance.

Let's look at a more concrete example, with the mutexes made explicit.

```
std::mutex m;
std::atomic<bool> updated;
foo shared;

void thr1() {
    m.lock();
    shared.write(new_data);
    m.unlock();
    updated.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
}

void thr2() {
    if (updated.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
        m.lock();
        data = shared.read();
        m.unlock();
    }
}
```

### Informal explanation

`m.lock()` is an acquire operation and `m.unlock()` is release.  This means that nothing prevents `updated.store(true)` from "floating" up into the critical section, past `m.unlock()` and even `shared.write()`. At first glance this seems bad, because the whole point of the `updated` flag was to signal that `shared.write()` had finished.  But no actual harm occurs in that case, because thr1 still holds the mutex `m`, and so if thr2 starts trying to read the shared data, it will just wait until thr1 drops it.

What would really be bad is if `updated.store()` were to float all the way up past `m.lock()`; then thr2 could potentially see `updated.load() == true` and take the mutex before thr1.  However, this cannot happen because of the acquire semantics `m.lock()`.

There could be some related issues in `thr2` (a little more complicated because they would have to be speculative) but again we are saved by the same fact: the `updated.load()` can sink downward into the critical section, but not past it entirely (because `m.unlock()` is release).

But this is an instance where a stronger memory order on the `updated` operations, although seemingly more expensive, might actually improve performance.  If the value `true` in `updated` becomes visible prematurely, then thr2 attempts to lock `m` while it is already locked by thr1, and so thr2 will have to block while it waits for `m` to become available.  But if you changed to `updated.store(true, std::memory_order_release)` and `updated.load(std::memory_order_acquire)`, then the value `true` in `updated` can only become visible after `m` is truly unlocked by thr1, and so the `m.lock()` in thr2 should always succeed immediately (ignoring contention by any other threads that might exist).

---

### Proof

Okay, that was an informal explanation, but we know those are always risky when thinking about memory ordering.  Let's give a proof from the formal rules of the C++ memory model.  I will follow the C++20 standard because I have it handy, but I don't believe there are any significant relevant changes from C++17.  See [intro.races] for definitions of the terms used here.

I claim that, if `shared.read()` executes at all, then `shared.write(new_data)` *happens before* it, and so by write-read coherence [intro.races p18] `shared.read()` will see the new data.

The lock and unlock operations on `m` are totally ordered [thread.mutex.requirements.mutex p5].  Consider two cases: either thr1's unlock precedes thr2's lock (Case I), or vice versa (Case II).

**Case I**

If thr1's unlock precedes thr2's lock in `m`'s lock order, then there is no problem; they *synchronize with* each other [thread.mutex.requirements.mutex p11].  Since `shared.write(new_data)` is *sequenced before* thr1's `m.unlock()`, and thr2's `m.lock()` is *sequenced before* `shared.read()`, by chasing the definitions in [intro.races] we see that `shared.write(new_data)` indeed *happens before* `shared.read()`.

**Case II**

Now suppose the contrary, that thr2's lock precedes thr1's unlock in `m`'s lock order.  Since locks and unlocks of the same mutex cannot interleave (that's the whole point of a mutex, to provide *mutual exclusion*), the lock total order on `m` must be as follows:

```
thr2: m.lock()
thr2: m.unlock()
thr1: m.lock()
thr1: m.unlock()
```

That means that thr2's `m.unlock()` *synchronizes with* thr1's `m.lock()`.  Now `updated.load()` is *sequenced before* thr2 `m.unlock()`, and thr1 `m.lock()` is *sequenced before* `updated.store(true)`, so it follows that `updated.load()` *happens before* `updated.store(true)`.  By read-write coherence [intro.races p17], `updated.load()` must **not** take its value from `updated.store(true)`, but from some strictly earlier side effect in the *modification order* of `updated`; presumably its initialization to `false`.

We conclude that `updated.load()` must return `false` in this case.  But if that were so, then thr2 would never have tried to lock the mutex in the first place.  This is a contradiction, so Case II must never occur.

Comment: `m.unlock()` is not a release *barrier*, it's a release *operation*. (Not just morally, that's formally true in ISO C++.) Later loads and stores can reorder into the critical section, and with operations inside the critical section.   Unlike if there was a release barrier there. https://preshing.com/20131125/acquire-and-release-fences-dont-work-the-way-youd-expect/  (Haven't read far enough to see if that invalidates your reasoning, but I think it's important to be careful with terminology here.  I think it's still likely that your conclusion is correct that it's safe, but not sure yet.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: Thanks, just sloppy wording re barrier.  I didn't mean a barrier/fence, and I do account for the later store reordering into the critical section.  As to "morally/formally", AFAICT the C++ standard only applies the terms "acquire" and "release" to atomic loads, stores and fences, and doesn't define mutex operations to be any of those.  So they are acquire/release in the usual sense of the words, but not in the standard's language.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a clear and concise explanation! I've also ended up using a release and acquire like you pointed out to avoid contention, also signals to other programmers what I intend with these barriers, except in cases where the memory barrier is irrelevant where I used the relaxed

Comment: [Release and Acquire with std::mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13359582) cites and quotes the C++ standard: "*a call that acquires a mutex will perform an acquire operation on the locations comprising the mutex*" etc.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Okay, thanks.  Their wording's not very consistent.  That particular sentence is actually from a non-normative note in [intro.races p3].  The normative text does say that any synchronization operation is either acquire, release or both, but the chapter on mutexes doesn't use that language again, nor bother to say which operations are of which kind.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Ah, I see.  I'd definitely seem it stated that mutex lock was an acquire operation, but maybe never looked at how the standard defined that.  I'd assumed it was stated more clearly / formally than that.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Terminology question re your earlier comment: generically, does "barrier" refer specifically to a standalone fence instruction, or more generally to any aspect of an operation that inhibits reordering?  For instance, I would think of using the word "barrier" to refer to the property of an acquire load that prevents later loads/stores from being reordered before it.  But maybe that is wrong.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Yeah, I'd say an acquire load includes a one-way barrier.  By contrast, I think "fence" is more generally agreed as being specifically a stand-alone 2-way barrier.

Answer (score 2):

Relaxed order means that ordering of atomics and external operations only happens with regard to operations on the specific atomic object (and even then, the compiler is free to re-order them outside of the program-defined order). Thus, a relaxed store has *no relationship* to any state in external objects. So a relaxed load will not synchronize with your other mutexes.

The whole point of acquire/release semantics is to allow an atomic to control visibility of other memory. If you want an atomic load to mean that something is available, it must be an acquire and the value it acquired must have been released.

Comment: I find this complicated (even with your explanation). I'm not OP but would appreciate some ASCII graphic diagram to visualize what you say. I think it'd make the answer go from good to great (for people like me).

Comment: @TedLyngmo: I don't really know what a diagram would look like. I mean, how do you draw "no relationship" between two things? They are unrelated.

Comment: I can appreciate that. Perhaps a diagram of what a proper relationship would look like and point out where OP:s attempt fails would do it? I'm not sure. I _am_ really unsure about atomics at this level but showing the proper way may be a good way to illustrate it.

Comment: The relaxed store by itself doesn't impose any ordering, but it is subject to the ordering imposed by other barriers - here, the barriers implicit in the mutex that protects `shared_conf`.  They ensure that the two critical sections must occur in a definite order (one must happen-before the other). If T2's critical section were to happen first, the synchronization between T2 unlocking the mutex and T1 locking it would imply that the load of `true` from `is_reconfigured` in T2 happens-before the store in T1, contradicting coherence.

Comment: So I think the code as it stands does ensure that the critical sections occur in the proper order.  It does not ensure that the mutex will actually be available when T2 attempts to take it - it might have to sleep, but when it wakes up, the updates from T1 will be visible.

Comment: @user17732522: I don't know what you mean by that.  `std::mutex::unlock()` synchronizes with `lock`, and therefore implies that every evaluation sequenced before the `unlock` happens-before every evaluation sequenced after the `lock`.  So I think that the `lock()` inside `shared_conf.set()` is in effect a full acquire barrier.  The relaxed store can be reordered *inside* the critical section, but it cannot be reordered *before* it, because that would pass the acquire barrier.  I can try to add a proof later.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: See https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/ which has diagrams of how acquire and release work wrt. other operations, and how that creates synchronization between threads.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks! I will read that (_again_ as it turns out). It's just something with proper diagrams that makes me understand things more easily. Edit: the comments under the article are very informative too. Great!

Comment: @NateEldredge Ah ok, I see your point now. I should have read your initial comment more carefully.